# DNS load balancer or round robin?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a dns server x.x.x.234 and it also runs haproxy on the same server.
Client connect to the dns directly.

I want to offer multiple servers because sometimes the network connection slows due to a bottleneck in haproxy.

Is there a way for the clients to connect to x.x.x.234 but have it load balanced just like you do with dns round robin connections? I guess not as DNS doesn't use a name?

Comment: "Client connect to the dns directly" makes no sense. Are you talking about a recursive nameserver? If that is the problem you can install more than one and your client should have one on its own machine.

Comment: Do not put a load balancer in front of a DNS server, you will get more problems than solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common and recommended to set up and offer multiple DNS servers (2 of them at least) to clients. Round Robin is a proper way of responding with DNS records and a default behavior, if mutiple answers are available (have been setup) indeed.

Yet, you can do that with L3 load balancer, if there is any restriction to stick to that single IP address.

Comment: I thought round robin relied on using a name ,like mydomain.com and then pointing to multiple server IPs? With DNS, when you change a dns setting in your ethernet or wifi you are only allowed to put in the exact IP address. Maybe I should have 1 DNS server with multiple proxies in the back and the dns can then pick any of them by pointing to a load balancer first?

Comment: Maybe the question was a bit confusing. Yes, RR is done that way when publishing records. For clients side, you may assign IP's of 2-3 name servers manually or via DHCP. An LB server is required only if you intend to stick to one IP

Comment: But how do I assign dns ia round robin or something similar. Clients enter dns in their network adapter as xx.xx.xx.1 - that can then balanced to 3 servers all running dns and proxies.

Comment: yes, it can be. any problem from there?